# how to make knitr use the same R session in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

how to make knitr use the same R session in RStudio?

FYI, I am working a huge amount of data (7 GB of RAM used by the R session) and I do not want to avoid having to use `load('data.RData')`

---

### Update

Knitr uses a new R session while running the `.Rmd`. Consequently, all my R objects can not be found. That's why I have to used the function `load('mydata.RData')`

Thanks

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "use same R session" and what file type you are using/how you use knitr currently.

Comment: This devastates reproducibility (one of core tenants behind the concept of R markdown files). `load('mydata.RData')` is a fine solution. I do understand the edge case where you have gigabytes of data in RAM already, tho. If it's not that, then you should really consider going the `load()` route for future Rmd work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you use `.Rnw` files type directly in the console (given the working directory is where your file resides):

```
knitr::knit("filename.Rnw")
# or 
knitr::knit2pdf("filename.Rnw")
```

The later also converts `filename.tex` to `filename.pdf`

For classical `.Rmd` files you can use the same

```
knitr::knit("filename.Rmd") 
# or 
knitr::knit2html("filname.Rmd")
```

For the newer workflow using `rmarkdown` package use

```
rmarkdown::render("filename.Rmd")
```

This works because by default the `knit` and `render` functions have the `envir` argument set to `envir=parent.frame()`, which is usually the global environment of your R-Session.

Calling `knit` or `render` by clicking the knit button in R-Studio on the other hand calls these functions with argument `envir=new.env()`.

Comment: And what about the `.Rmd`??

Comment: Explaining "why" (i.e. `envir` param value) might make this a more helpful answer.

Comment: What is `new.frame`?  Did you mean `new.env`?